# repository X not found: does not exist or no pull access-docker

Tags: docker, pull

I created one docker repository by importing from tar ball.

```
REPOSITORY                                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sample-one-adv6-6.19.1.403   latest              0e9312c86f03        33 minutes ago      1.74 GB
```

but when i use

```
  docker image pull -a sample-one-adv6-6.19.1.403
```

i get error message

```
   Error response from daemon: repository sample-one-adv6-6.19.1.403 not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

How can i pull all tagged images in the repository?